# Nextjs + i18Next load all lang json files when init page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, localization, i18next

I'm using Nextjs + next-i18next for multi lang. When the page init, it loads all lang json files en.json, vi.json, ja.json,...

Are there any way to **ONLY** load the lang json file for the current language?

The site has been exported static and deployed on AWS S3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, on server side it will preload all languages: https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/master/src/config/createConfig.ts#L46

Comment: thanks for the reply, but there are anyway if I export static and deploy on AWS S3